# Getting binding generated ListView elements inside PivotItem in windows phone 8.1

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, windows-phone-8.1, pivot

In a Windows Phone 8.1 application I have the following (simplified) structure:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="transparent">
 <Pivot x:Name="MainPivot" Binding = {...}>
     ...
     <Pivot.ItemTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
                <ListView Binding = {...}>
                    ...
                </ListView> 
          </DataTemplate>
     </Pivot.ItemTemplate>
  </Pivot>
</Grid>
```

So a `ListView` is contained in each `PivotItem`. In response to a click event, I need to loop through the `ListView` elements and perform some task using C# code. In conclusion I need a method to obtain a collection of `ListView` (for example a `List<ListView>`). How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can save resources and all the clutter running through the tree controls and use simple style:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="transparent">
    <Grid.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Setter Value="0.5" Property="Opacity"/>
        </Style>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <Pivot x:Name="MainPivot" Binding = {...}>
        ...
        <Pivot.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ListView Binding = {...}>
                    ...
                </ListView>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Pivot.ItemTemplate>
    </Pivot>
</Grid>
```

More information around [styles.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745683(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: Thank you for the tip.I just realized I commited an error in my explanation. I need to change the opacity of the `stackpanel` elements that are children of `ListView`. Anyway I need to change dinamically the opacity, in response to a click event,